# Setting up Game Center using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm quite new to Swift and iOS programming, and I was wondering how I would set up a Game Center leaderboard, add players' scores to the leaderboard and update players' scores using Swift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you Google how to set up Game Center, you should find some tutorials that will help you, they are a little out of date with iOS 8 so below are the bits that aren't so easy to translate over.

Authenticating a player

```
let lp = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
if lp.authenticated == false {
    lp.authenticateHandler() { (vc, error) -> Void in
        println(error)
    }
}
```

Add score to leader board

```
leaderboardName = "My first game"
let scoreObj = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: leadeboardName)
scoreObj.context = 0
scoreObj.value = score
GKScore.reportScores([scoreObj], withCompletionHandler: {(error) -> Void in
    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success", 
                          message: "Score updated", 
                         delegate: self, 
                cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
    alert.show()
})
```